# Get values from an array received from subject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ionic5

I have a project in Ionic5 that request some itens to an api.
I have a similar code as below:

**Item.service.ts**

```js
getItens(): Observable<Item[]> {
    const subject = new Subject<Item[]>();
    this.http.get<Response>('host').subscribe(data => {
        // Some cool things
        subject.next(data.items)
    }, error => {
        subject.error(error.message)
    });

    return subject.asObservable();
}
```

**items.page.ts**

```js
items: Item[] = [];

    loadItems() {
        this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(items => this.items = items);
    }
```

In a page, I have an interval that update the items. Everything works fine if I use `this.items = items` but the list disappears and reappears every load, probably because the entire value of `this.items` is changing

So I tried to just insert differents values in array:

```js
items: Item[] = [];

    loadItems() {
        this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(items => {
            items.forEach(item => {
                const value = this.items.find(i => i.id == item.id);
                if(!value) this.items.unshift(item);
            })
        })
    }
```

Unfortunately the subject doesn't await the results from service so just an empty array is rendered in the page. An ugly solution that I found was use a timeout to await the results, but the ms has to change based on length of item list.
An observation is that if I log items from **item.page.ts** it will be print an array with length 0, but with values

[image]

I'd like to avoid Promises itself and keep Observables if it's possible.
I cannot return the request directly, because I need to manipulate the data.

Is there any way to await `subject.next()` to render the items? If not, what logic can I use to show the item list?

**SOLVED**

The problem was solved using a specific logic of the project. But all answers below will be works in normal environments and has a lot of information in the comments. I really recommend read all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first I guess that you have a memory leak in you Item.service.ts file because every time that you call loadItems() you are subscribing and not unsubscribing for this you can use `pipe(first())`
and also `getItems()`function creates a Subject on each call.

Here problem of refreshing is when it replaces the array as you said. although you can check each element of array to see if it's updated or not.

seems lodash has such a function to check equality of two objects

https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/33-how-to-compare-2-objects/

Also to test it:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lodash-tdggzs?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

And the code:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

export class SampleService {
  items: Item[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  get getItems(): Item[] {
    return this.items;
  }

  fetchData(): void {
    this.http
      .get<Item[]>('host')
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe((newArray) => {
        this.updateMyArray(newArray);
      });
  }

  updateMyArray(newArray: Item[]) {
    newArray.forEach((item) => {
      const itemInLocalArray = this.items.find((x) => x.id === item.id);
      if (itemInLocalArray) {
        const isItSame = _.isEqual(itemInLocalArray, item);
        if (!isItSame) {
          this.items[this.items.indexOf(itemInLocalArray)] = item;
        }
      } else {
        this.items.push(item);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

so in code above you create array inside service to save the data and there is no need for Subject.

and to get the data you can first connect to array inside service with

`this.items = this.sampleService.getItems;`

and call

`this.sampleService.fetchData()`
to fetch data from server and **because items array is synchronous and also available, you can use it whenever you want.**

```
 // Inside Component
  items: Item[] = [];
  constructor(private sampleService: SampleService) {
    this.items = this.sampleService.getItems;
  }
  
  fetchData(){
    this.sampleService.fetchData();
  }
```

Comment: I have already solved the problem with a specific logic of thhe project structure. But lodash was really useful, thanks bro!

Comment: Also, the structure you show me is the ideal for my project. Everything is working well.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a subject in your `getItems()` service. the http client methods return observables by default

```
getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
  return this.http.get<Response>('host');
}
```

with that, your component would then be the one that does the subscribing.

```
loadItems() {
    this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(items => this.items = items);
}
```

by returning the observable from the service, and moving the subscription to the component, when you subscribe to the method, you will be able to set items when the HTTP request completes

Comment: The problem is that after I get the items from api, I need do some requests again to manipulate and return it. Besides, I really want to avoid write this logic in page component.

Comment: if you need to perform additional API requests after the first, you can use additional rxjs operators to combine observables into one (forkjoin, concatMap...), allowing you to merge multiple http requests into single observable. alternatively what you could do is create a property on your service that is a behavior subject. i.e. `items$: BehaviorSubject<Item[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Item[]>([]);`. you could have your service method update this property via `next()`. finally your component subscribes to this property. keeping your business logic in the service and your component dumb

Comment: Forgive me for the question, but the operators will be use inside a pipe? And pipe itself doesn't change the value returned, right?

Comment: rsjx provides operators that allow you to change the value of the observable, or to simply tap into its value. i.e. `this.http.get(url).pipe( map( data => {//your code here}))` will convert the data returned from the http request to whatever you return in the map operator. whereas `this.http.get(url).pipe( tap (data => { //youcode here} ))` will not change the result coming back from the http observable. there are other operators such as `switchmap` that will allow you to switch the value of an inner observable. rxjs is very powerful and useful, I'd suggest getting familiar with it.

Comment: I have already solved the problem, but your help was really useful. I'll mark your answer as right because in normal environments it'll solve the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Like Edward said, you don't need that subject.

```js
// Move your "cool things" and all the other stuff in that subscription into a pipe
getItens(): Observable<Item[]> {

retrun this.http.get<Response>('host').pipe(
       map(data => {
        // Some cool things
        return data.items
      }),
      catchError(error => {
       // if you need to only pass error message you can do it here but you could probably skip this. Make sure you re-thow the error though, so other subscribers see it as an error and not just a valid result.
       return throwError(error.message);
      })
);
}
```

As for your issue of the whole list getting re-rendered, `*ngFor` has a `trackBy` parameter which will help with this.  You provide a function, and it helps angular know which items were changed in the array and to only re-render those.

The angular docs have the `trackBy` syntax https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

It would be something like this
template:

```html
<my-component *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy: trackByFn> </my-component>
```

Component

```js
trackByFn(index, item) {
    return item.id // or whatever the key property is
  }
```

Comment: I need the subject because the items has to be manipulate e used in other request and the response of this request that will be returned. Use a function instead of an array problably solves the problem, but and about performance? In this way, the cost will not be high?

Comment: Some pipe operators manipulate data.  What you return from map is what subscribers will get.  `tap` is annother operator that lets you do things, but not change what is returned.  Without knowing what "some cool things" are, I can't really recommend how to change it.  Your repainting issue should get fixed by the `trackBy` feature though.